# 権威DNSサーバをオンプレミスに設置するメリットについて

Tags: dns

レジストラでドメインを取得して、オンプレミスの権威DNSサーバに取得したドメインを委譲(管理)するメリットはありますでしょうか？

そのままレジストラのネームサーバで管理していた方が、セキュリティ・可用性の面で良い気がしますが、「xxxのためにはオンプレミスの権威DNSサーバで管理した方が便利」などあればご教授いただきたいと思います。

なお、現在考えている構成は、オンプレミスにインターネットからアクセス可能なWebサーバが1台あり、そのWebサーバーに紐づくドメインの管理について設計しております。

Answer (score 0):

DNSサーバの設計運用に精通しているのであれば自前のDNSサーバの「自由にコントロールできる」点はメリットになりますが、知識がないのであればメリットどころかデメリットになります。

上記は一例で、一般的に前提条件なしでメリットを探すのは意味がないので、まず要件に適合しているのかどうかで考えてください。